# A strange phenomenon using casting in C

Tags: c

the following code:

```
int main() {
    int small_num   = 0x12345678;
    int largest_num = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    printf("small: without casting to short: 0x%.8x, with casting to short: 0x%.8x\n", small_num>>16, (short)(small_num>>16));
    printf("large: without casting to short: 0x%.8x, with casting to short: 0x%.8x\n", largest_num>>16, (short)(largest_num>>16));
    return 0;
}
```

gives me the output (using [codepad](http://codepad.org/Ae9nK6sl)):

```
small: without casting to short: 0x00001234, with casting to short: 0x00001234
large: without casting to short: 0xffffffff, with casting to short: 0xffffffff
```

That's seems extremely strange. Anyone have an idea why it happens this way?

Comment: Shift operation will maintain the sign of `int`, and the sign is stored in most significant bit of `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/3763263/395718

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5253194/395718

Comment: If you are expecting 0x0000FFFF, & the result with 0xFFFF after shifting.

Answer (score 2):

When you are casting to (short) in the printf call, then the compiler will cast it from short back to int, which is the parameter which is passed to printf. Therefore, 1234 will be mapped to 1234, and ffff (which is exactly -1) is mapped to ffffffff. Note that negative integers are expanded from short to long by adding "on bits" on their left.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

The hexadecimal constant has type `unsigned int`. When converted to `signed int` the value becomes `-1`. Right-shifting a negative value *usually* leaves the sign-bit unchanged, so `-1 >> 16` is still `-1`. A `short int` passed to a variadic function gets promoted to `signed int` which, when interpreted as an `unsigned int` by the `%x` conversion specifier, prints out `0xffffffff`.

### Long answer

However, your code is broken for a number of reasons.

#### Integer conversion

`int largest_num = 0xFFFFFFFF;`

The type of the hexadecimal constant is the first of the following types in which its value can be represented: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.

If `int` has more than 32 bits, you're fine.
If `int` has 32 bits or less, The result is **implementation-defined** (or an **implementation-defined signal** is raised).

Usually, `largest_num` will have all bits set and have the value `-1`.

#### Shifting a negative value

`largest_num>>16`

If the value of `largest_num` is negative, the resulting value is **implementation-defined**. Usually, the sign bit is left unchanged so that `-1` right-shifted is still `-1`.

#### Integer promotion

`printf ("0x%.8x\n", (short)(largest_num>>16));`

When you pass a `short int` to a variadic function, the value will be promoted to `int`. A negative value will be preserved when converted to the new type.

However, the `"%x"` conversion specifier expects an `unsigned int` argument. Because `unsigned int` and `signed int` are not compatible types, the **behaviour** of the code is **undefined**. Usually, the bits of the `signed int` is re-interpreted as an `unsigned int`, which results in the original value of the hexadecimal constant.

#### Calling a variadic function

`printf(...);`

`printf()` is a variadic function. Variadic functions (typically) use different calling conventions than ordinary functions. Your code invokes **undefined behaviour** if you don't have a valid declaration of `print()` in scope.

The usual way to provide a declaration for `printf()` is to `#include <stdio.h>`.

---

Source: [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the last public draft of the current C standard).