# using shift-right , something is wrong

Tags: c

I defined a struct named queryData like the code below. When I tried to using shift and right operation to operate and assign a data, qdata.data.data4[0], printing the data out, there is something wrong that the data I stated before is **a char** which is 8 bits, but when I **print** it it actually 32 bits,**0xffffff8b**. I wonder how it could be like this. Thank you.

```
int main(void){
    union Data{
        char data2[2];
        char data4[4];
    };
    struct queryData{
        char byte; // 2bytes or 4bytes.
        union Data data;
    };
    struct queryData qdata;
    unsigned long int data;
    data = rand()%4294967295;
    qdata.byte = 4;
    qdata.data.data4[0] = (char)(data>>24);
    qdata.data.data4[1] = (char)((data<<8)>>24);
    qdata.data.data4[2] = (char)((data<<16)>>24);
    qdata.data.data4[3] = (char)((data<<24)>>24);
    printf("%ld\n",data);
    printf("%x\n",qdata.data.data4[0]);
    printf("%x\n",qdata.data.data4[1]);
    printf("%x\n",qdata.data.data4[2]);
    printf("%x\n",qdata.data.data4[3]);
    printf("%x",(unsigned int)(1804289383<<8)>>24); 
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The result is below:
[The result after run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xdj4M.png)

Comment: Right shifting signed values is implementation defined. And left-shifts can invoke undefined behaviour. Use unsigned fixed width types!

Comment: Oh, and **don't post links or images of text**

Comment: [Signed right shift = strange result?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3763263/995714). don't use magic numbers like 4294967295, use `0xFFFFFFFF` or `~0u` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong `printf` format. Use `%hhd` for `char` as a numerical value. If you'd prefer to print it in hex, you'd have to use `unsigned char` as a type, instead of `char`.

What you are observing is that your `char` is promoted to `int` and passed as such to `printf`. You then print that `int` as an `unsigned` in hex. Because your platform seems to have a signed `char` type and uses two's complement for negative values, you see the pattern with all the starting bits switched to on.

Comment: Got it. Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Vararg functions such as printf will promote all integers smaller than int to int. Since char is an integer (8-bit signed integer in your case), your chars are being promoted to int via sign-extension.

Since 8b have a leading 1-bit (and are negative as an 8-bit integer), they are being sign-extended while the others in your sample don't.

To avoid such promotion you have to use length specifier in printf:

```
printf("%hhx\n",qdata.data.data4[1]);
```